# how to sort values of 1st column and print only corresponding values of third column using awk

Tags: sorting, awk

I tried to sort the file using `awk '{print $0|"sort -t',' -nk1 "}'` but I want to print only the third column of sorted file. Input file:

`1   4   7   9
9   7   4   1
4   6   8   9
1   2   3   4
5   4   5   2`

the expected output:

`3
7
8
5
4`

Comment: post a fragment of your input file

Comment: I'm not sure you need awk to do that, `sort` should suffice.

Comment: I think you may mean `sort -t',' -nk1 file | awk -F,  '{print $3}'`

Comment: Thank you @dawg I tried 
`sort -t',' -nk1 file | awk -F, '{print $3}'`
as out put i get an empty file, it didn't print anything..:(

Comment: if I use `sort -t',' -nk1 file | awk -F, '{print $1}' ` it prints same as for `sort -t',' -nk1 file ` it prints only when i use print $1 elce it does not print.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
sort file|awk '{print $3}'
3
7
8
5
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways "*to print only the **third** column of sorted file*":

with `tr` + `cut` command:

```
sort -n file | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3
```

---

with `awk`:

```
sort -n file | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: `sort -n file | cut -d, -f3`  will do the same thing.

Comment: `sort -t',' -nk1 file | awk -F, '{print $3}' `
it prints an empty file.. :(

Comment: @user3132983, that's why I asked for *post a fragment of your input file*

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I already started doing it using Gnu awk's `asorti`:

```
$ awk '
    { a[$1 "," $3]=$3 }      # get the data to a hash (*)
END { n=asorti(a)            # sort a by the index
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {    # for each ordered index
          split(a[i],b,",")  # split and
          print b[2]         # print the latter part
      }
}' file
3
7
8
5
4
```

`(*)` If using only `$1` as the key there will be a collision when `$1=1`. For this data using `$1 "," $3` won't produce a collision and will sort the `$3` as well. However, there could be a collision. The correct way would be to keep a count of the keys and have a sub `for` loop to print those out (or have keys and values in different arrays indexed with `NR`). That will be left as an exersize.